# Print Fibonacci Series using map or reduce in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions

I want to print Fibonacci Series using  map() or reduce() function in Javascript. I am not able to find anything online for it. I am not quite sure on what my condition would be in the map().

I am basically writing

```
fib(n){
return new Array(n-1).fill(1).map((_,i) => *This is where I am confused* ) ;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain *why* you want to use `map` or `reduce` for this?

Comment: It's not that this is particularly hard to do with `reduce`, but it feels like the wrong tool for the job, as does `map`.

Comment: I had the same doubt, why was this question down voted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's relatively easy to do this with `reduce()`, just check for the index and act accordingly:

```js
function fib(n){
  return new Array(n).fill(1).reduce((arr, _ ,i) => {
      arr.push((i <= 1) ? i : arr[i-2] + arr[i-1])
      return arr
  },[]) ;
}
console.log(fib(10))
```

`map()` is not an especially good fit because you don't have a natural way to access the earlier states.

Comment: ninja'ed by a minute :-)

Comment: `ninja'ed` made me laugh out loud @LucaKiebel

Comment: Nice ^^ Didn't use that term in a long time

Comment: Your result is only 9 integers, not 10 as `fib(10)` would suggest is the desired result

Comment: Thanks @DarrenSweeney. Fixed it.

Comment: @MarkMeyer What if I want to print just the nth number of this sequence?

Comment: @DipeshRajendraDesai save the results to a variable and index into it: `var f = fib(n)` `f[n]` will be the nth number.

Answer (score 4):

a savage one liner example i wrote for my students :

```js
const fiboReduce = level => new Array(Math.max(0, ++level)).fill(0).reduce((acc, val, index) => [...acc, ...((index > 1 && [acc[--index] + acc[--index]]) || [])], [0, ...((level > 1 && [1]) || [])]);

console.log(fiboReduce(20));
```

long version director's cut (pardon my french) :

```js
const fiboReduceExplained = level => {
 // on force le rang minimum à 1 en utilisant Math.max
 // on ajoute 1 pour bien calculer jusqu'au rang souhaité
 // on créé un tableau vide qui a pour longueur le rang souhaité
 let array = new Array(Math.max(1, ++level));
 array.fill(0); // on le blinde de 0 jusqu'au bout
 let startValue = [0]; // valeur de départ
 if(level > 1) startValue.push(1); // cas particulier pour fibo(0)
 let fibo = array.reduce((acc, val, index) => { // reduce !
  if(index > 1) { // index strictement supérieur à un, on est sorti des valeurs de départ
   let next = acc[index - 1] + acc[index - 2]; // on calcule le terme suivant 
   acc.push(next); // et on l'ajoute au tableau
  }
  return acc; // on retourne le tableau pour la boucle suivante
 }, startValue); // valeur de départ du reduce
 return fibo; // on retourne le résultat
}

console.log(fiboReduceExplained(20));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map it with `Array.from` and two start values for getting the series.

```js
function fib(length) {
    return Array.from({ length }, ((a, b) => _ => ([b, a] = [a + b, b, a])[2])(0, 1));
}

console.log(fib(10));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to your problem. "elem" is the current current value, "index" is the current index and "currentArray" is the instance of the array.

```
fibonacci = (n)=>{
    return new Array(n).fill(0).map((elem,index, currentArray)=>{
        if(index === 0){
            currentArray[index] = 0;
        }else if(index === 1){
            currentArray[index] = 1;
        }else{
            currentArray[index] = currentArray[index-2]+currentArray[index-1];
        }
        return currentArray[index];
    });  
}
```

You can see that for each step we modify the array element using the current index and then return the element at the current index. Finally you get the array of fibonacci series after the iteration is completed.

Answer (score 0):

[I've tried in my concole it works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4y1i.jpg)You can follow this. Hope it helps you try it running from the google console.

```
function Fibonacci(n) {
    var f = [];
    for (var c = 0; c < n; ++c) {
        f.push((c < 2) ? c : f[c-1] + f[c-2]);
    }
    return f;
}
```

Comment: `You can follow this.` Maybe not, can you explain it?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney It works fine I've also attached the screenshot of it you can check it there.

Comment: My point was that by explaining what you're doing, and how it works, is helpful and does not then promote copy and paste

Comment: @DarrenSweeney
The loop will run until c<n.
In the first case when c=0, it first checks if c is less than the input 'n', if its true then it will go in the ternary operator. If c is less than 2 then it will print 0 because c is zero now. It will continue the if loop until c<2. Once if statement becomes false then else statement will be executed for the remaining c=2,3,4. and so on. Hope i'm able to justify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce and concat

```
const fib = (n) => {

    [...Array(n)].reduce(
    (acc,val,i) => acc.concat(i > 1 ? acc[i-1]+ acc[n-2] : i),
    [])
    
    }

fib(10)
```

Comment: Please add supporting details to your answer to improve it.